# How to disable expansion of elements in isotope

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, element

I have several elements in isotope. When you click them, by default, they expand to a bigger version. Is there way to disable this function from occurring?

Comment: Which function? Which elements? And the answer is yes, you can

Comment: @A.Wolff you're perfectly right, and of course that he can ;)